# cross-browser blur for a complete web page using jQuery

Tags: jquery, blur

i have a problem i can't find a satisfiable solution for.

i need to add an overlay to my page that is shown when the user clicks on a link. when the overlay is shown, all other content should be blurred. this needs to be cross-browser, flash-less, and work for a web page with arbitrary content (i.e., images, text, styled html-elements, etc).

i googled but all i could find were some solutions showing blur effects for text, distinct elements, or else. i'm aware of blur.js, but this does not seem to work.

is there any simple way to get a whole web page blurred? i'd prefer to do this in jquery, since css3 is not entirely cross-browser...

Comment: You could simply use a mask, which would render the page unclickable. something like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/aaaheatair/mU3MA/13/)

Comment: I hope you have seen http://nbartlomiej.github.com/foggy/   [ Works in all browser including IE8+ ]

Comment: yep i did this already. i have this overlay and it's somewhat transparent. but what i need now is that the rest of the web pages content i can still SEE through this overlay gets blurred. just like the effects used in photoshop or gimp.

Comment: the previous answer was a response to roy finleys comment. rakesh: many thanks! foggy() works great!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the colorbox lighbox (A lightweight customizable lightbox plugin for jQuery), it is very easy to use and it ave a lot of features.

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox